# How to use fireEvent with specialkey ENTER

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I want my field to submit when it is out of focus. (blur event).
The event that triggers submission, is an ENTER key event.
So I did this:

```
outOfFocus: function(field, event) {
    console.log('Lost focus');
    field.fireEvent('specialkey', field,
        Ext.create('Ext.EventObject', {
            key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER
        })
    );
},
```

But it doesn't work.
Firebug says something about: TypeError: c is not a constructor.

Any thoughts?

A bit more of the surrounding code as requested in a comment:

The form:

```
var editPic = "<img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/pencil.png' alt='edit' height='24' width='24' style='margin-left: 10px;'/>";
var submitPic = "<img id='submitPic' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/bzimages/submitPic.png' alt='edit' height='24' width='24'/>";

Ext.define('BM.view.test.Edit', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.test-edit',

layout: 'anchor',
title: 'Edit Test',
defaultType: 'displayfield',

items: [
    {name: 'id', hidden: true},
{
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    afterSubTpl: editPic,
    cls: 'editable'
},
{
    name: 'nameEdit',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    xtype: 'textfield',
    hidden: true,
    cls: 'editMode',
    allowBlank: false,
    afterSubTpl: submitPic
}
]

});
```

The controller:

```
    this.control({
        'test-edit > displayfield': {
            afterrender: this.showEditable
        },
        'test-edit': {
            afterrender: this.formRendered
        },
        'test-edit > field[cls=editMode]': {
            specialkey: this.editField,
            blur: this.outOfFocus
        }
    });
```

Is this enough to understand what I'm doing?

Comment: Could you give us more of the surrounding code?  It looks like you're defining outOfFocus as a property to something.

Comment: @Reimius: I have added some more code, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer. It seems less than adequate, but gets the job done all the same.

I've reused the event that triggered this function call:

```
outOfFocus: function(field, event) {
        console.log('Lost focus');
        event.keyCode = event.ENTER;
        field.fireEvent('specialkey',field, event);
    },
```

Still looking for a better way to do this.